# What is the best way to take backup of sqlite database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

What would be the best way to take backup of sqlite database on Android such that the data stays in user's Google Drive? I want to ideally take incremental backups instead of backing up the entire data all the time.

Currently the strategy I am using is to backup all the three database files `{db_name}.db`, `{db_name}-wal.db` and `{db_name}-shm.db` to user's google drive once a day and then restore all these files for the user when user logs into a new device. Here's the part of WorkManager code that I am using for backup:-

```java
        File databaseFile = new File(context.getDatabasePath("db1").getAbsolutePath());
        File databaseWalFile = new File(context.getDatabasePath("db1-wal").getAbsolutePath());
        File databaseShmFile = new File(context.getDatabasePath("db1-shm").getAbsolutePath());
        if (!databaseFile.exists() || !databaseWalFile.exists() || !databaseShmFile.exists()) {
            return Result.SUCCESS;
        }
        long totalBackupSize = databaseFile.length() + databaseWalFile.length() + databaseShmFile.length();
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());
        DriveResourceClient driveResourceClient = Drive.getDriveResourceClient(getApplicationContext(), account);
        final Task<DriveFolder> appFolderTask = driveResourceClient.getAppFolder();
        final Task<DriveContents> createContentsDbTask = driveResourceClient.createContents();
        final Task<DriveContents> createContentsDbWalTask = driveResourceClient.createContents();
        final Task<DriveContents> createContentsDbShmTask = driveResourceClient.createContents();
        Tasks.whenAll(appFolderTask, createContentsDbTask, createContentsDbWalTask, createContentsDbShmTask)
                .continueWithTask(task -> {
                    DriveFolder parent = appFolderTask.getResult();
                    DriveContents dbContents = createContentsDbTask.getResult();
                    DriveContents dbWalContents = createContentsDbWalTask.getResult();
                    DriveContents dbShmContents = createContentsDbShmTask.getResult();
                    if (dbContents != null && dbWalContents != null && dbShmContents != null) {
                        Utility.copy(new FileInputStream(databaseFile), dbContents.getOutputStream());
                        Utility.copy(new FileInputStream(databaseWalFile), dbWalContents.getOutputStream());
                        Utility.copy(new FileInputStream(databaseShmFile), dbShmContents.getOutputStream());
                        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setTitle(AppConstants.GoogleDriveBackupDbFileName)
                                .setMimeType(AppConstants.DatabaseMimeType)
                                .build();
                        MetadataChangeSet changeWalSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setTitle(AppConstants.GoogleDriveBackupDbWalFileName)
                                .setMimeType(AppConstants.DatabaseMimeType)
                                .build();
                        MetadataChangeSet changeShmSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setTitle(AppConstants.GoogleDriveBackupDbShmFileName)
                                .setMimeType(AppConstants.DatabaseMimeType)
                                .build();
                        return Tasks.whenAll(driveResourceClient.createFile(parent, changeSet, dbContents),
                                driveResourceClient.createFile(parent, changeWalSet, dbWalContents),
                                driveResourceClient.createFile(parent, changeShmSet, dbShmContents));
                    }
                    TaskCompletionSource<DriveFile> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<>();
                    tcs.setException(new Exception("Failed to copy database file"));
                    return Tasks.whenAll(tcs.getTask());
                }).addOnSuccessListener(driveFile -> {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(PreferenceConstants.INSTANCE.getPreferenceName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putLong(PreferenceConstants.INSTANCE.getLastGoogleDriveBackupTime(), new Date().getTime());
                    editor.putLong(PreferenceConstants.INSTANCE.getFileSize(), totalBackupSize);
                    editor.apply();
                    Log.v("BackupWorker", "Backup successful");
                    result[0] = Result.SUCCESS;
                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    Log.e("BackupWorker", "Unable to create file", e);
                    result[0] = Result.FAILURE;
                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                });
```

Backup and restore using the above strategy but my concerns are:-

- What if internal implementation changes in future where we need to backup some files apart from wal and shm? Simply taking a backup of the main database file wasn't working for me.
- This strategy is inefficient because it requires me to take the backup of entire database all the time. Is it possible to do incremental backups here?

I considered storing the backups in CSV files and storing those on Google Drive instead. And then I could just write the changes to the CSV file for every subsequent backup. However I feel this would increase dev effort by quite a bit. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Simply taking a backup of the main database file wasn't working for
>   me.

If you properly checkpoint the database using the [TRUNCATE](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_checkpoint) option before performing the backup then there should be no need to backup the -wal and -shm files (as they would be empty).

Also if you close all connections then that should also complete the checkpointing. For example consider the following (where `logDBSizeInfo` outputs the file sizes, `addsomeData` and `deleteSomeData` do as they say)

```
    mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
    logDBSizeInfo(this,DBHelper.DBNAME);
    if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase(),"table1") < 1) {
        addSomeData(100000);
        deleteSomeData(1000);
    } else {
        addSomeData(1000);
        deleteSomeData(100);
    }
    logDBSizeInfo(this,DBHelper.DBNAME);
    mDBHlpr.close();
    //checkpointIfWALEnabled(this,DBHelper.DBNAME);
    logDBSizeInfo(this,DBHelper.DBNAME);
```

Results in :-

> ```
> 05-24 20:25:47.195 D/DBSIZEINFO: Database Size is 34312192
> 05-24 20:25:47.195 D/DBSIZEINFO: Database -wal file Size is 0 path is /data/user/0/aso.so56286308backupwal/databases/mydb-wal
> 05-24 20:25:47.196 D/DBSIZEINFO: Database -shm file Size is 32768 path is /data/user/0/aso.so56286308backupwal/databases/mydb-shm
> 05-24 20:25:47.199 D/ADDSOMEDATA: Adding about 1000 rows
> 05-24 20:25:47.365 D/ADDSOMEDATA: Deleting about 100 rows
> 05-24 20:25:47.397 D/DBSIZEINFO: Database Size is 34656256
> 05-24 20:25:47.397 D/DBSIZEINFO: Database -wal file Size is 420272 path is /data/user/0/aso.so56286308backupwal/databases/mydb-wal
> 05-24 20:25:47.397 D/DBSIZEINFO: Database -shm file Size is 32768 path is /data/user/0/aso.so56286308backupwal/databases/mydb-shm
>
> <<<<<<<<<<After Close>>>>>>>>>>
>
> 05-24 20:25:47.400 D/DBSIZEINFO: Database Size is 34656256
> 05-24 20:25:47.400 D/DBSIZEINFO: Database -wal file does not exist
> 05-24 20:25:47.400 D/DBSIZEINFO: Database file -shm does not exist
> ```

I use the following to ensure that the file is checkpointed before backing up (just the database file):-

```
private void checkpointIfWALEnabled(Context context, String databaseName) {
    Cursor csr;
    int wal_busy = -99, wal_log = -99, wal_checkpointed = -99;
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(databaseName).getPath(),null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode",null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        String mode = csr.getString(0);
        if (mode.toLowerCase().equals("wal")) {
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint",null);
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                wal_busy = csr.getInt(0);
                wal_log = csr.getInt(1);
                wal_checkpointed = csr.getInt(2);
            }
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)",null);
            csr.getCount();
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint",null);
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                wal_busy = csr.getInt(0);
                wal_log = csr.getInt(1);
                wal_checkpointed = csr.getInt(2);
            }
        }
    }
    csr.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Another option that could reduce the size of the backup would be to use [VACUUM INTO](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html). I haven't tried this approach. However, logging is used, so it may also be wise to checkpoint, afterwards (You could then use the file not only as a backup but to also replace the original file).

Incremental backups of the database would probably prove to be impractical and more time consuming, unless you basically had transaction already logging built and would therefore likely not be asking the question. In general an incremental backup system is driven by relatively easily detected changes.